# problem connecting to the administrator

Tags: php, admin

Good evening,

I put my wordpress site online but I cannot access my administrator area. When I put my username and password I have this error:

> Remarque : Constante DRICUB_DRIVING_SCHOOL_IMG_URL déjà définie dans /home/hsmx1991/public_html/wp-content/themes/dricub-driving-school/functions.php sur la ligne 14
>
> Attention : Impossible de modifier les informations d'en-tête - en-têtes déjà envoyés par (sortie démarrée à / home / hsmx1991 / public_html / wp-content / themes / dricub-driving-school / functions.php: 14) dans /home/hsmx1991/public_html/wp-login.php en ligne 521
>
> Attention : Impossible de modifier les informations d'en-tête - en-têtes déjà envoyés par ( sortie démarrée à /home/hsmx1991/public_html/wp-content/themes/dricub-driving-school/functions.php:14) dans /home/hsmx1991/public_html/wp-login.php en ligne 537

> Avertissement: Impossible de modifier les informations d'en-tête - en-têtes déjà envoyés par (sortie démarrée à /home/hsmx1991/public_html/wp-content/themes/dricub-driving-school/functions.php:14) dans / home / hsmx1991 / public_html / wp-includes /functions.php en ligne 6270

I would like some help please.
Thank you in advance for your response.
Cordially.

Comment: I'm not sure what your errors say, they're in french, can you post english versions?

Comment: I also see you use https://themeforest.net/item/dricub-driving-school-wordpress-theme/20920140 if you need help with that theme you need to speak with their support route, 3rd party theme dev support is off topic here

Comment: I contacted support and they fixed the problem.
Thanks Tom for your answer